# Using an IF statement to output a named cell from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use an IF statement to output a named cell value from another sheet (in the same doc)?

I have a large sheet with various product prices for my store and so one of the fields is the cost of shipping. At the moment I have a sheet with various values for shipping and each one has the cell with a name - eg. a cell on that sheet (call it "sheet2") has a value of £6.50 and it's called "DPDLocalShipping" and another cell has a value of £10 and is called "DPDLocalShippingBox"

On "sheet1" where all my products are, if I use "=DPDLocal" it outputs the value no problem but I'd like to use a statement in the shipping field that takes a product value and if it's above a certain value, it would either output a shipping cost from DPDLocal or DPDLocalLarge but if I do something like this

```
=if( J7 > 225, "DPDLocalShippingBox", "DPDLocalShipping")
```

The value in J7 is the product price.

When I try this formula, it just renders out DPDLocalShipping in the shipping field so obviously something is wrong but I'm not entirely sure what or how to get the £ value to show in that field.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). For the 101 on spreadsheet formulas, visit [GFCGlobal](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/creating-simple-formulas/1/). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to named ranges, remove the double quotes in the formula, like this:

`=if( J7 > 225, DPDLocalShippingBox, DPDLocalShipping )`

Comment: that's done the job, thank you